# Unexpected current draw at idle load with MIC28517 Buck switching regulator?

Tags: switching-regulator

I've designed and fabbed a PCB with a design for the MIC28517 IC and at 62.5V Vin I get a current draw of 50mA of the IC and Inductor which do get warm(3W dissipated on the inductor and IC) I've mostly followed the manufacturer design recommendations with the schematic and just and changed the layout a bit but this is the schematic of the manufacturer eval board for the IC:

[image]

and My Design:

[image]

AGND and GND is not actually separated as I suspected there isn't realy a sensitive analog circuitry on the IC and the separation could cause ground loops.

Did anyone have experience working with this IC?
What is suspected to cause that problem?

Wave forms:

VIn = 62.5V
VOut = 5V
SW Pin Out with 47Ohm resistor in series with probe:

[image]

Output wave
[image]

Another Working one for ref:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this draw with no load? Do you have any scope captures of the input /output / SW node?

Comment: At no load, is it using forced PWM mode or some kind of power saving mode? Is the inductor saturating? Check inductor saturation current versus maximum switch current.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the problem. 50mA draw and 3W without connecting load are the problems you are referring. what are the design parameters like Vout, Max Iout, Max Vin etc

Comment: I'm just looking for a general direction to what usually causes these kind of IC designs to consume that much power(gets quite hot) with no load connected as I've mentioned sins I don't have any experience with designing with these IC's I have made a prototype module that worked fine before that but now it sits on a board that contain two of those MIC28517 sync regulators which work just fine interms of efficiency under loads but that excessive idle power consumption and heating put bothers me. Anyways I' posting the SW out pin and VOut of each regulator one that works and one that doesn't.

Comment: There you go!!!

Comment: try connecting a small load and see if that changes anything. Some of these designs don't like not having a load.

Comment: @danmcb Yeah that's what I'm trying to figure out is why the thing is that I have around the same design with the same Ic of other board with a layout copy paste and these work fine under load only consuming 3mA on idle and don't heat up at all.